# C++ socket to server from different interface

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, posix

I'm learning POSIX socket programming. 
And now i have client socket and can connet to server and send data.
But my machine have different interfaces with different "white" IP adresses. 
How can I use different interface for my client socket to connect to server. 
At the end I want server to see that i'm connection from defferent IP adresses.
Please Help =)
Thx

Comment: Your reputation is enough to know that your question does not follow the guidelines.

Comment: `bind` the socket to a specific interface before invoking `connect`.